# Nonsingular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I am kind of curious about the nice properties between affine nonsingular curve and projective nonsingular curve. In my feeling to define sheaf of nonsigluar curve, most of the resources are focusing on  nonsingular projective curve and why not on affine nonsingular curve. Thanks.

Comment: Sheaves are defined by local data, so it doesn't matter if they are *defined* on an affine or a projective curve. However, it does matter when you start proving things, because affine and projective curves have very different properties.

Comment: The general idea is: projective is the global case, and affine is the local case.